# How do I show taskbar while playing minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Guys I need help with the task bar. I pressed F11 and the task bar disappeared. I pressed it again and it just shows a small screen of minecraft. I want it where minecraft is fullscreen but you can still see the taskbar. I tried Crtl + Esc and it didn't work. Please tell me a way and be specific.

Comment: Do you have the usual Windows buttons on the top-right of minecraft while it's in it's small window size?

Comment: Do you mean you want to play the game in windowed mode ?

Comment: You maybe would make better if you include screenshots of your actual situation.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft has two modes, full screen and windowed. Pressing F11 toggles between these.

**Full screen**

Minecraft covers the whole screen. You cannot do anything on Windows (or the Mac desktop, if you have an Apple computer) and the task bar will be gone. If you want to use the task bar, you will have to exit full screen.

**Windowed mode**

Minecraft is running in a Window. You can resize the Window like any other. But first you will need to make the mouse appear. You can do that by pausing the game (Esc). Then you can drag the edges of the Window until it is as big as you want. If you are on Windows, you can even press a simple button to do that. It is the middle button in the top right of the screen. Keep in mind, this does not work on Mac.